# Is there a function in scala used to remove items from a list?

Tags: scala, list, element

I am programming a todo list that I can add elements to and remove them as well.  I am having problems trying to remove items from my mutable list.

```
val list = MutableList[Any]()

def removeItem(){
     val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("\nEnter item to remove:\n").stripLineEnd

    for(i <- 0 to list.size){
        if (list[i] == input){
           list[i] = 0
           list -= input
        }
    }

}


def menu(option: Int): Boolean = {
  option match {
    case 1 =>
      addItem()
      true
    case 2 =>
      println("Enter item to remove")
      removeItem
      true
    case 3 =>
      println("\nHere is your todo list:")
      display()
      true
    case 4 =>
      println("selected quit")
      false
    case _ => // the else case
      println("Unrecognized command")
      true
  }
}
```

When I call the function from my menu to remove an item, I am expecting my remove item function to go through my mutable list and remove the item in it that is = to the user's input and allow me to do this each time I call the function, but I am getting this, error: ';' expected but '=' found.
           list[i] = 0

Comment: MutableList is designed to be "mutable" but not growable (append/remove). Use ListBuffer instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer`.
Examples:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

scala> var mutableList = new ListBuffer[String]()
mutableList: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()

scala> println(mutableList)// empty
ListBuffer()

scala> mutableList += "First element"
res1: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(First element)

scala> println(mutableList)// 1 element
ListBuffer(First element)

scala> mutableList += "second element"
res3: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(First element, second element)

scala> println(mutableList)// 2 elements
ListBuffer(First element, second element)

scala> // Deleting...

scala> mutableList -= "First element"
res5: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(second element)
```