# how to divide, multiply or add any value in List[List[Double]] in scala

Tags: scala, list

```
Listt = List(List(22.3 , 44.3), List(12.1), List(10.2))
```

If I want to add `5` with `22.3` of index 0, how can I do that?

Like, after I add 5 the list should be like this :

```
Listt = List(List(27.3 , 44.3), List(12.1), List(10.2))
```

Comment: So you want to add 5 to only the first element of the first List? Or to the first element of every List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JArgente mentions, scala list are inmutable, so if you are going to perform these kind of actions (to update the list), you might consider use `scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer`.

Some examples here: [Is there a function in scala used to remove items from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58652048/is-there-a-function-in-scala-used-to-remove-items-from-a-list/58652120#58652120)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to know that in scala list are inmutable so it it impossible to change a element of the list as you can do in java for example. The way to do this could be use the .head method to get the first element, then make the same operation to get the first element of the inner list, create the new head you want and then use the prepend method :: with the .tail of the original inner list and then again append the inner list as the head of the outer list

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching. Maybe it's not an elegant solution, but it solves your problem though:

```
list match {
  case head :: tail =>
    val newHead = head match {
      case h :: t => (h + 5) :: t
      case _ => head
    } 
    newHead :: tail
  case _ => list
}
```

For:

`val list = List(List(22.3, 44.3), List(12.1), List(10.2))`

Will produce:

`List(List(27.3, 44.3), List(12.1), List(10.2))`

Comment: The question is for any value in List[List[Double]], not just head

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc Nope. As I see from the question other elements of the lists are unchanged

Comment: Title says any ``how to divide, multiply or add any value in List[List[Double]] in scala`

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc probably the title is misleading

Comment: It would be better if @broadcasted clarify the problem

Answer (score 0):

As the other Questions already explained, scala lists are immutable, therefore you can only create an updated copy of the list. A helpful utility is the `updated` method. It gives you a new list where a value at an index 'n' is replaced against a new element.

```
// Here we replace the number at index '1' (the '2') against a '9'
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4).updated(1, 9)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 9, 3, 4)
```

This method can be to solve your problem in a more compact manner than using pattern matching and allows to work with numbers at arbitrary indices.

```
scala> val l = List(List(22.3 , 44.3), List(12.1), List(10.2))
l: List[List[Double]] = List(List(22.3, 44.3), List(12.1), List(10.2))

scala> l.updated(0, l(0).updated(0, l(0)(0) + 5))
res1: List[List[Double]] = List(List(27.3, 44.3), List(12.1), List(10.2))
```